# How to change the size of a collision box of a circle sprite in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am designing a game however I have postponed my development to focus on the collisions of sprites in the shape of circles.

I am not 100% sure how the 'pygame.sprite.collide_circle' command works with its parenthesis however I have included it within my Collidecheck variable as well as created a new variable called 'collided' to then include within Collidecheck as 'collided = None'.

My Ball class uses the ball objects which are all circles. There are two which should interact being ball and llab.

```
class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height, herex, herey):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() 
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, BLACK, [int(width/2),int(height/2)], int(width/2), 10)
        self.rect.x = herex
        self.rect.y = herey

    def moveRight(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x += pixels
    def moveLeft(self, pixels):
        self.rect.x -= pixels
    def moveUp(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y -= pixels
    def moveDown(self, pixels):
        self.rect.y += pixels
```

The 2 circles are in sprite groups as I am practising using them

```
ball = Ball(100, 100, 50, 50)
llab = Ball(100, 100, 350, 250)

g = pygame.sprite.Group(ball)
h = pygame.sprite.Group(llab)
```

Within the main game loop, ball moves so I can test the hitboxes. If you watch the console as it is printing the collision check, you can see it working.

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        ball.moveLeft(5)
        ballFollow.moveLeft(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        ball.moveRight(5)
        ballFollow.moveRight(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        ball.moveUp(5)
        ballFollow.moveUp(5)
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        ball.moveDown(5)
        ballFollow.moveDown(5)

    Collidecheck = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(ball, h, False, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)
    print(Collidecheck)
    screen.fill(RED)

    g.draw(screen)
    h.draw(screen)
```

I originally expected to see within the console the collision be between ball and llab but ball and llab have a really large hitbox which I don't want. I want to only see the hitboxes of both these circles extend to their actual shape and no larger. It seems their hitboxes are double their sizes I think although I am not sure

P.S I understand I could use maths and might have to, I was wondering if anyone had better knowledge of the sprite functions to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See documentation for [pygame.sprite.collide_circle](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

> If the sprites have a "**radius**" attribute, that is used to create the circle, otherwise a circle is created that is big enough to completely enclose the sprites rect as given by the "rect" attribute.

So you have to create `self.radius` in `Ball` and it can be smaller then ball's size.

---

How it works ? It gets centers of both sprites and use [Pythagorean  theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) (`a**2 + b**2 = c**2`) to calculate distance between these points. If it is smaller then `sprite1.radius1 + sprite2.radius2` then you have collision.

BTW: PyGame has [pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.distance_to) to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks furas for the help!